# How do I install a plugin from a local .zip or .jar file in Aptana Studio 3?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, installation, aptana

I have a locally packaged plugin that isn't available from any update server (I built and exported it from source code, using Eclipse.)  The plugin installs and works in the Eclipse environment.

Now I'd like to use it in my standalone Aptana Studio 3 installation.  Is there a documented method of installing a .ZIP or .JAR file containing a working Eclipse plugin into Aptana Studio 3?

If this is well-documented elsewhere, a URL is all I need!  :D

**Edit**: I realize there may be many reasons why the plugin doesn't work in Aptana; the issue here is that I can't find a simple way to install the plugin from within Aptana.  I've tried "Add Repository -> Local" and "Add Repository -> Archive" but neither method recognizes the packaged plugin.  I've also tried dropping the jar file into the Aptana 3 'plugins' dir and restarting -- no love.  But there are no error messages or log entries to help understand why I can't install the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a dependency issue. In some cases, a plugin may depend on another plugin that is missing from the product (e.g. Aptana Studio, in this case).

What I suggest is to install Aptana Studio as a plugin into a classic Eclipse 3.7 installation. Then, install your plugin just like you tried before.

Hope that helps.